# Django - NoReverseMatch at /project/3/evillio

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm working on a portfolio project and i face a strange problem when trying to list a project, ( class-based-views-DetailView). More specifically when trying to list a project for example /project/3/evillio i got following error `Reverse for 'project-detail' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']` but when i add a new project, i'm able to list /project/3/evillio with no problem, however i got the same error on the next project /project/4/urban.

For example i add 2 projects in project table (using Postgres) then going to list details of each project. Click on project1 and works fine. Then click on project 2 and i got error above. Then i add a third project in project table and going to list details of each project. Click on project1 works fine, click on project2 works fine, click on project3 and i got the same error as on project2 before adding project3.
I hope is more clear.

urls.py

```
path('project/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>', WorkProjectsDetailView.as_view(), name='project-detail'),
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'pages/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'projects'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(IndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slider_projects'] = 
        Project.objects.all().filter(slider_project=True)
        return context

class WorkProjectsView(ListView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'work/work.html'
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'projects'
    ordering = ['-date_created']

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkProjectsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['categories'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context

class WorkProjectsDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Project
    template_name = 'work/project-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'single_project'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(WorkProjectsDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['next'] = Project.objects.filter(id__gt=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('pk').first()
        return context
```

work.html

```
<div class="projects-list gallery">
  {% if projects %}
    {% for project in projects %}
    <div class="item brand">
        <a href="{% url 'project-detail' pk=project.pk slug=project.slug %}" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="work"
            data-dsn-grid="move-up">
            <img class="has-top-bottom" src="{{ project.featured_image.url }}" alt="" />
            <div class="item-border"></div>
            <div class="item-info">
                <h5 class="cat">{{ project.category }}</h5>
                <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
                <span><span>View Project</span></span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  {% else %}
      <div class="col-lg-8">
        <p>No Projects Available</p>
      </div>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```

index.html

```
{% for project in slider_projects %}
<div class="work-item slick-slide">
    <img class="has-top-bottom" src="{{ project.featured_image.url }}" alt="">
    <div class="item-border"></div>
    <div class="item-info">
        <a href="{% url 'project-detail' pk=project.pk slug=project.slug %}" data-dsn-grid="move-up" class="effect-ajax">

            <h5 class="cat">{{ project.category}}</h5>
            <h4>{{ project.title }}</h4>
            <span><span>View Project</span></span>
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

project-detail.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

    <main class="main-root">
        <div id="dsn-scrollbar">
            <header>
                <div class="headefr-fexid" data-dsn-header="project">
                    <div class="bg w-100" id="dsn-hero-parallax-img" data-dsn-ajax="img">
                        <div class="bg-image  cover-bg" data-overlay="4"
                            data-image-src="{{ single_project.hero_image.url }}"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="scroll" data-dsn-animate="ajax">
                        <span class="background"></span>
                        <span class="triangle"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="project-title" id="dsn-hero-parallax-title" style="margin-top: 100px;">

                        <div class="title-text-header">
                            <div class="cat">
                                <span>{{ single_project.category}}</span>
                            </div>
                            <span class="title-text-header-inner">
                                <span data-dsn-animate="ajax">{{ single_project.title }}</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="sub-text-header" data-dsn-animate="ajax">
                            <h5>Published</h5>
                            <span>- {{ single_project.date_created }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="project-page__inner">
                        <div class="h-100">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-end h-100">
                                <div id="descover-holder" class="col-lg-12 project-meta__content">
                                    <div class="link">
                                        <a target="_blank"
                                            href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/57437111/Under-Armour-Cal?tracking_source=search%7CPhotography">View
                                            Website</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="root-project">

                    <div class="container intro-project section-margin">
                        <div class="intro-text">
                            <div class="title-cover" data-dsn-grid="move-section" data-dsn-opacity="0.1"
                                data-dsn-duration="170%" data-dsn-move="0%">
                                Nile
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h2 data-dsn-animate="text">A whole new brand</h2>
                                <p data-dsn-animate="up">Striking and powerful Aston Martin Vantage captivates you at
                                    the first sight. We couldn’t resist the temptation to create a series of beautiful
                                    images for this car.</p>
                                <a class="bottom-link" data-dsn-animate="up"
                                    href="https://www.behance.net/gallery/66646747/Nile" target="_blank">
                                    <span></span>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <div class="inner">
                                            <p>VISIT SITE</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container section-margin">
                        <div class="img-box-small dsn-parallax-full" data-dsn-grid="move-up">
                            <img src="{{ single_project.photo_1.url }}" alt="">
                            <div class="cap">
                                <span>Web Design</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-fluid section-margin">
                        <div class="img-box-small dsn-parallax-full" data-dsn-grid="move-up" data-dsn-triggerhook="0">
                            <img src="{{ single_project.photo_2.url }}" alt="" data-dsn-y="30%" data-dsn-scale="1.08">
                            <div class="cap">
                                <span>Web Design</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container intro-project section-p section-margin">
                        <div class="intro-text text-center">
                            <div class="title-cover" data-dsn-grid="move-section" data-dsn-opacity="0.1"
                                data-dsn-duration="170%" data-dsn-move="0%">
                                Nile
                            </div>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <h2 data-dsn-animate="text">
                                    The Brief team has been sincerely committed to
                                    designing great communication around our projects. Our customers love
                                    their
                                    creative work - and so do we!
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!--Video-->
                    <div class=" " data-dsn="video" data-overlay="4" data-dsn-ajax="img">
                      <video class="image-bg cover-bg dsn-video" controls loop muted>
                        <source src="{{ single_project.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
                    </div>

                    <!--<div class="container section-margin">
                        <div class="img-box-small dsn-parallax-full" data-dsn-grid="move-up">
                            <img src="{{ single_project.photo_3.url }}" alt="">
                            <div class="cap">
                                <span>Web Design</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->

                    <div class="container-fluid section-margin">
                        <div class="img-box-small dsn-parallax-full" data-dsn-grid="move-up" data-dsn-triggerhook="0">
                            <img src="{{ single_project.photo_4.url }}" alt="" data-dsn-y="30%" data-dsn-scale="1.08">
                            <div class="cap">
                                <span>Web Design</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="next-project" data-dsn-footer="project">
                    <div id="dsn-next-parallax-img" class="bg">
                        <div class="bg-image cover-bg" data-overlay="2"
                            data-image-src="{{ next.featured_image.url }}"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="dsn-next-parallax-title" class="project-title">
                        <a href="{% url 'project-detail' next.pk next.slug %}" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="next-project">
                            <div class="title-text-header">
                                <div class="title-text-header-inner">
                                    <span>{{ next.title }}</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="sub-text-header">
                                <h5>Next Project</h5>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: please explain in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for comment! I've updated initial question with more details. I hope is more clear.

Comment: This error is coming from the `{% url 'project-detail' pk=project.pk slug=project.slug %}`.  Is there another location that this url is being called?

Comment: Yes, in index.html and work.html. Listed above.

Comment: Do you need to have the `slug` in the url? If you just use the id you should have everything you need right?

Comment: what does "work/project-detail.html" look like?

Comment: @Ben, yes i would like to have slug in the url. If i use <id> how can i modify url, view and template?

Comment: What do you mean how looks like. I paste it in the question FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're receiving is because of this line toward the bottom of `project-detail.html`:

```
<a href="{% url 'project-detail' next.pk next.slug %}" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="next-project">
```

if there is no `next` (`context["next"]`), then django can't figure out the url, and you get the error you're seeing.

Wrap the last segment for the link to "next" with `{% if next %}`:

```
{% if next %}
<div class="next-project" data-dsn-footer="project">
    <div id="dsn-next-parallax-img" class="bg">
        <div class="bg-image cover-bg" data-overlay="2"
            data-image-src="{{ next.featured_image.url }}"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="dsn-next-parallax-title" class="project-title">
        <a href="{% url 'project-detail' next.pk next.slug %}" class="effect-ajax" data-dsn-ajax="next-project">
            <div class="title-text-header">
                <div class="title-text-header-inner">
                    <span>{{ next.title }}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-text-header">
                <h5>Next Project</h5>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```